# Not breaking .get(fieldname='match') API after moving fields in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say we have a `Person` model with `email`, `bounced` and `bounced_date` fields.

We want to allow users to have more than one email address. We create a separate `EmailAddress` model with `address`, `bounced`, `bounced_date`, and a `ForeignKey` field to `Person`. We use `order_with_respect_to` so users can have email addresses ordered by preference. Writing the migration needs a few lines of SQL.

We also define `email` property in the `Person` model which return the `address` field of the first related `EmailAddress`, so we don't need to make code changes everywhere the `email` field was used on our `Person` objects.

The last thing I cannot find a way to do is finding a way to have `.get(email='example@example.com')` still working. `EmailAddress` are unique so there should still be a unique user attached to each email address.

I know I can use `.get(emailaddress__address='example@example.com')`, but if possible, I would like not having to change the code everywhere in the project. To be clear, I would like `email` to be mapped to `emailaddres__address` in `.get` and `.filter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the related_name on your EmailAddress ForeignKey to the Person model

```
Person.objects.filter(<related_name>__address='example@example.com')[0]
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: I know I can use `.get(emailaddress__address='example@example.com')`, but if possible, I would like not having to change the code everywhere in the project. To be clear, my question is how I can map `email` to `emailaddres__address` in `.get` and `.filter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep that exact syntax, but you can make a slight adjustment to look it up in the related model.

```
.get(emailaddress__email='example@example.com')
```

Comment: I know I can use `.get(emailaddress__address='example@example.com')`, but if possible, I would like not having to change the code everywhere in the project. To be clear, my question is how I can map `email` to `emailaddres__address` in `.get` and `.filter` methods.